# Why do i have to occasionally use htmlentities twice

Tags: php

Sometimes i have to use htmlentities twice to convert the text correct (see example), why is that, and is there a other solution.

example:

```
<?php
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
  $result = db_query("INSERT INTO example (id, example) VALUES ('" . htmlentities(htmlentities($_POST['example'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "', '')");
}
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="example" value="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['example'])); ?>">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't know how you put data into database. You should use special functions for that as for example mysql_real_escape_string ( http://docs.php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ) to achieve this.

Comment: It isn't possible to tell why you need to encode it that way because we can't see the input. (The answer is that you probably *don't* need to do that)

Comment: That's where you should never use `htmlentities()`. If you're using it there, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: That said, `htmlentities` is wildly inappropriate for preparing data to be put into a database at all. Use prepared statements and bound arguments to escape your data (or at least using a database escaping routine, not an HTML escaping routine). Use `htmlspecialchars` before inserting data into an HTML document, not a database.